# Filtering the rows from Query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get only rows that exist in both season. in both season the products have same `code`
For example in season 2016 I have 315 products in `products` table and for 2017 only 28 products

The following query delivers 315 + 28 products.

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE P.active = 1
AND S.season IN ( 2016, 2017 )
ORDER BY P.code
```

what I need is that query should deliver only 28 products from 2017 and 28 from 2016 which have the same code as of 2017's products.

Comment: Within each year, can Product.code duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like intersection:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM products P
INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE P.active = 1
AND S.season=2016
INTERSECT
SELECT P.*
FROM products P
INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE P.active = 1
AND S.season=2017
ORDER BY P.code
```

Or, another aproach. Find records from 2016, find from 2017 and match codes:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM products P
    INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
    WHERE P.active = 1
    AND S.season=2016
) T1
JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM products P
    INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
    WHERE P.active = 1
    AND S.season=2017
) T2 ON T1.Code=T2.Code
ORDER BY T1.Code
```

Comment: Seems to work partially, as I need the The IDs at the end, as the IDs are not same on intersection will not deliver any result :(

Comment: Added another approach. Make sure you attach table structures and sample data. It is much easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **change and condition**:

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE P.active = 1
AND P.id_season IN ( 2016, 2017 )
ORDER BY P.code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE P.active = 1
AND S.season IN ( 2017 )
Union All
SELECT *
FROM products
where active = 1
AND Prod_id in (
    SELECT Prod_Id FROM products P INNER JOIN Season S ON S.id = P.id_season
    WHERE  P.active = 1 AND S.season IN ( 2017 ) 
)
```

Does  this work ?